# Overlay views programmatically RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to overlay 2 views.

My AdView should be "floating" above my GameView.

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    AdView admobView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(admobView);
    View gameView = createGameView(config);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(admobView);


private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setId(R.id.classic); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}
```

this will only sets the gameview below the adview.

Thank you

edit: too much code...

Comment: So what's your problem? you said at the end of question `this will only sets the gameview below the adview`

Comment: Hopefully this picture will describe what I'm trying to do. I want the AdView inside the GameView. http://s1.directupload.net/images/140829/w3nkbf2s.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}
```

**Update**

Also change the adding order:

```
View gameView = createGameView(config);
layout.addView(gameView);
AdView admobView = createAdView();
layout.addView(admobView);
```

Comment: @KennyPew what is the view you're adding first to the layout? try to add `gameView` first then the `adView`.